# Can't Control Volume on Lockscreen with Volume Buttons on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I upgraded to iOS 5 and I just noticed that I can no longer control the volume level on the phone by pressing the volume buttons while the screen is locked. I recall distinctly that I was able to do this on iOS 4. Has something changed or did I miss something?

Comment: No, nothing has changed. Volume buttons should work as they did with iOS4. ¿Have you jailbroken your iPhone? ¿Have you tried pressing them a bit harder?

Comment: Ah. I had a jailbroken iOS 4. It must've been something I installed then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

★ [Settings > Sounds > Ringer and Alerts > Change with Buttons = **ON**]

Tapping the home button twice should bring up the audio player/volume slider on the lock screen. While it's visible try the buttons on the side — depending on whether or not you see the volume slider move on the screen should tell you if your buttons are not actually working.

---

This is straight from the iOS 5 user guide:

When iPhone is locked, nothing happens if you touch the screen. iPhone can still receive calls, text messages, and other updates. You can also:

- Listen to music
- Adjust the volume using the buttons on the side of iPhone (or on the
  iPhone earphones) **while you’re on a phone call or listening to music**.

Use the center button on iPhone earphones to answer or end a call, or to control audio playback.

- [iPhone User Guide For iOS 5.0 Software](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf%28) (PDF)